# Register a service with multiple instance in Consul

Tags: docker-compose, consul, service-discovery

I have a couple of microservices that I want to register in Consul, so that they can find each other and communicate.
Everything runs on docker compose.

I am wondering how that would work if one of the two services has multiple replicas. How does Consul (or docker compose) deal with that? Is there some sort of internal load balancing or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul supports registering multiple instances/replicas of a service. When a consumer queries the Consul catalog, Consul will return information for each of the registered service instances.

If the consumer/client is querying Consul via [DNS](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/dns), the client's DNS resolver will ultimately be responsible for choosing the endpoint to connect to from the list of IP's in the DNS response.

If the client is querying Consul via the HTTP API (e.g., [`/v1/agent/health/service/:service`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/health#list-nodes-for-service)), the client must implement its own logic to select an upstream instance from the list of instances returned in the API response.

See the [query services](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/get-started-service-discovery#query-services) section of the Register a Service with Consul Service Discovery tutorial for more info.